# "set ic" command in vim results in non matching of pattern

Tags: vim

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3

I am using the above version of vim. I search for ALWays_ff and there's no match. If I search always_ff, I get a match. I am baffled..

Comment: Works fine for me in 7.3. I just enter the command `:set ic` and there it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
:set scs?
```

to see have you enable the `smartcase` mode, if so, it will override `ignorecase` setting when you input upper case word

For more info, type `:h smartcase`

Comment: That explains it. I removed "set smartcase", and it now works. Thanks.